# Plumbing: water expansion tank, hot water heater & circulator replaces within a week of each other

Tags: plumbing

Hoping you all could lend your expertise....

We recently replaced the water expansion tank after the plumber said we needed a new one. A week later the water heater burst and were told we needed a new hot water heater. After spending 2500$ on a “high efficiency” system and install, a couple days later it had a small leake. The plumber said it was no big deal and fixed it in two minutes. Three hours after he left the heat in zone 1 shut off and the circulator is making a loud noise and is extremely hot to touch. We replaced the circulator a year ago with a new one by Taco. We’re now being told the circulator pump is bad and needs to be replaced.

Could any of these issues be related to each other? The timing of everything breaking within days of each other are puzzling. Thoughts or suggestions?

Thanks in advance for your feedback!

Comment: i think that you are missing some information ..... why was the plumber called in the first place? ..... where was the small leak?

Comment: Good point- initially we called because the water expansion tank was leaking. This resulted in he backfllow valve to start flowing. The day after the expansion tank was replaced zone 1 stopped getting heat. Plumber returned and bled lines. The heat returned. It was actually a couple weeks later that the seam of the water heater burst flooding the basement and cutting heat to the house. Within a few days of replacing water heater, there was a small leak. Plumber fixed in just a few mins. Three hours after he left the heat in zone 1 shut down and the circulator is making a loud buzzing noise.

Comment: Your comments suggest that you are heating with a domestic water tank. Is the tank also supplying domestic hot water to your faucets? If so, is the system using a heat exchanger or is the system potable approved(stainless or bronze components)? Could you post a picture of system? Hydronic heating is very complicated and a picture speaks volumes. I can definitely help you figure out what is going on. Sounds like cavitation (air bubbling out of solution) and air lock burnt out your pump. But I need more info.

Comment: Pressure cycling a DHW unit can cause mechanical failure, especially if they are getting older and have some internal corrosion.  Your plumber must love you.